# Can't connect to MongoDB remotely (even though bindIp is not set)

Tags: linux, mongodb, server, database-connection, iptables

I'm trying to solve this one for few hours now and I have no idea why it's not working. I set up mongod with

```
mongod --dbpath /some/path
```

so that bind_ip is not set (mongod is listening on all interfaces).
I set all iptables' policies to ACCEPT and flushed all rules (so I can be sure that iptables doesn't block anything) - iptables -S:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION
-N FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-N FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
-N FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-N FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-N FORWARD_direct
-N FWDI_public
-N FWDI_public_allow
-N FWDI_public_deny
-N FWDI_public_log
-N FWDO_public
-N FWDO_public_allow
-N FWDO_public_deny
-N FWDO_public_log
-N INPUT_ZONES
-N INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-N INPUT_direct
-N IN_public
-N IN_public_allow
-N IN_public_deny
-N IN_public_log
-N OUTPUT_direct
```

I double and triple checked my server's public ip and it's 100% correct. But no matter what I do, when I try to connect to mongo from my local machine with:

```
mongo <servers_ip>
```

I get

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.11
connecting to: servers_ip/test
2017-08-08T18:18:30.689+0200 warning: Failed to connect to servers_ip:27017, reason: errno:113 No route to host
2017-08-08T18:18:30.690+0200 Error: couldn't connect to server servers_ip:27017 (servers_ip), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
exception: connect failed
```

Does anyone have any idea what else can I do to make this work?

EDIT:
Output of netstat -tanp | grep mongod:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4302/mongod
```

Comment: Is the server accessible on port `27017`? maybe the ports are not forwarded by the router.

Comment: Please add the output of `netstat -tanp | grep mongod`

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Added in edit

Comment: @nadavvadan well, it says it listens, however I am not able to connect remotely. The server runs on OVH VPS, is it possible that they are blocking ports?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so it seems like from my side everything was fine. It was my VPS provider - OVH - who blocked the port and I couldn't do anything about this, but change the mongod port to some lower value. Thanks @nadavvadan for the suggestion.

Comment: What port did you use? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up your user

you need to set a user and password for your database to get access
use your_db

`db.createUser({ user: 'user', pwd: 'password', roles: [{ role: 'readWrite', db:'yourdb'}] })`

2. Enable auth and open MongoDB access up to all IPs

`sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf`

```
`# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
security:
  authorization: 'enabled'`
```

3. Open port 27017
   Make a new Custom TCP on port 27017, Source: Anywhere, 0.0.0.0/0
4. Last step: restart mongo daemon (mongod)

   `sudo service mongod restart`
5. Logging in using the mongo shell on your laptop

   `mongo -u user -p password serverip/your_db`